# converting the form of a natural log

Tags: integration, logarithms, substitution

in Integrating $\cfrac{(25-x^2)^{1/2}}{x}...$ using $ x=5\sin(u)$

I get: $-5\ln|(5/x((25-x^{2})^{1/2})/(x)$

book gets $+5\ln( 5/x -((25-x^{2})^{1/2})/x$

both graph to the same curve... but am having trouble seeing how to convert my answer to the book answer.  see delta's **+/-**

thanks

Comment: Please use MathJax. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/171839

Comment: Could you make it a bit nicer?

Comment: ?....what?.......